# I'm facing problem with newsapi.org (API), I can't display the news articles on get news button, console shows no errors now

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, newsapi

```
function getNews() {
  fetch(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=india&apiKey=<MyApiKey>",
    { headers: new Headers({ "X-Requested-With": "abcd" }) }
  )
    .then((a) => a.json())
    .then((response) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.articles.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
          "<div class='article' style='padding-top:20px;'> <img class='image' style='float:left; width:150px;' src='" +
          response.articles[i].urlToImage +
          "' > <h1>" +
          response.articles[i].title +
          "</h1>" +
          response.articles[i].source.name +
          "<br>" +
          response.articles[i].description +
          " <a href='" +
          response.articles[i].url +
          "'target='_blank'>" +
          response.articles[i].url +
          "</a></div>";
      }
    });
}
```

My console doesn't show any errors now, but onclick getNews() does not display anything!!

```
<body>
    <button class="btn" onclick="getNews()">Get News Here.</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I was hoping to display the news by this api, (I tried to use 'in' as my country code but didn't work).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY0ciWj8oco&t=24s - I was trying to implement it by this video since yesterday, fixed some errors I got but right now I have no errors in console nor on my window after I click on 'get news here' button, it does nothing!! Please help!!

Comment: I just tried again, but now the console shows me this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)
127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "The origin"... is not valid JSON

Comment: what is `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`?

Comment: That means that the response you are getting is not JSON. Instead of `a.json()` try `a.text()` and tell what happens.

Comment: Tried a.text but got these errors 404,403 & length undefined!!  I was trying to implement this news API and found this video about it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY0ciWj8oco . here he also mentions about the Heroku app URL

Comment: to use this API we need to request temporary access to it, so after that, I got no errors in the console but still, no news displayed!!!

Comment: Are you sure you have used your API key? dumb question of mine, but it happens way to often that people don't put authorized API keys, or even forget to put them in their code...

Comment: 100% I've used the API key, I copied the whole code and after pasting it here then I edited the API key to <MyApiKey>

Comment: Hey bro, I got it... before country code in was not working so, I used India but in the API docs the code was actually "in"!! but big thanks to you for taking some of your time for me!!

Comment: here's the GitHub: https://github.com/mjshubham21/News-API.git

Comment: I can't host it though, I've mentioned the error in the readme!! If you happen to know the solution pls help!!

Comment: Glad you got it solved, as for the other problems, you may ask a seperate question here or another StackExchange site and I'd be willing to help you. We'll have to close this question down as it was merely because of a typo.